# why is it showing ,Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tableHTMLExport is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I using the tableHTMLExport library to convert a html table to pdf.The page is an .ejs page that is being served from a server.The actual contents of the table is fetched from a database and drawn to the page using javascript.it shows the error 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tableHTMLExport' when the download pdf button is clicked.I have placed the required script tags as mentioned in https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/export-table-json-csv-txt-pdf.html  and every scripts seems to be loaded correctly on the client side when i checked the chrome dev console.
page:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.7">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.4.1/sketchy/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/adminstyle.css">
    <title>Eventer</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="h2">
    <span class="span">Eventer</span><Span><a href="/users/adminlogout" class="btn btn-secondary" style="float:right;">Logout</a></Span><Span><a href="/users/closeevent/confirm" class="btn btn-secondary" style="float:right;">Close current event</a></Span><Span><a href="/users/setevents" class="btn btn-secondary" style="float:right;">Set New Eventlist</a></Span>
   </div>
   <h2  id="currentevent">Current event:</h2>
   <div class="subhead">
       <h1>Viewby:House</h1>
       <select  class="form-control" id='house' name="house">
        <option>Orchid</option>
        <option selected>Tulips</option>
        <option>Lailac</option>
        <option>sunflower</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <li style="margin-left: 10px;font-size: 20px;" id="househead"></li>
   <div class="table">
       <table id="housetable">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Batch</th>
            <th>Semester</th>
            <th>Events</th>
        </tr>

       </table>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="getdata('byhouse')">Get details </button>
   <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="downloadpdf()">Download pdf </button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.3.5/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/scripts/tableHTMLExport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/scripts/admin.js"></script> //admin.js is my script

</body>
</html>
```

javascript:-

```
function downloadpdf(){
    $("#housetable").tableHTMLExport({

        // csv, txt, json, pdf
        type:'pdf',

        // file name
        filename:'sample.pdf',



      });
}
```

Comment: open your browser console and make sure all scripts fully loaded.

Comment: yes,every script  is loaded and gives a status of 200 on the network section of chrome dev tools.but the tableHTMLExport.js and admin.js shows a status of 304 which i think is not an error and just means that it is taken from a cached resourse,Thanks